# Can you nest one for loop inside the other with them having the same loop variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, turtle-graphics

Consider this piece of code:

```
import turtle
import sys

# function that draws a square using turtle graphics:

def drawSquare(t, sz):        # t is a turtle object and sz is the size of the square
    for i in range(4):
        t.forward(sz)
        t.left(90)

def main():
    sys.setExecutionLimit(300000)
    wn = turtle.Screen()      # setting up the window
    wn.bgcolor('lightgreen')

    alex = turtle.Turtle()    # setting up the turtle object
    alex.color('blue')
    alex.speed(10)

    for i in range(24):       # drawing the shape
        drawSquare(alex, 100)
        alex.right(15)

    wn.exitonclick()

main()
```

In the last for loop I used `i` as my loop variable. But inside the for loop I also called the `drawSquare()` function which also contains a for loop with a loop variable named `i`.

When I run this program, it gives the same output as when I would change one of the two loop variables' name to `counter` for example. Is it just a coincidence or can you nest one for loop inside another with them having the same loop variable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `i` in `drawScope` is a different object in a *world* (scope) of its own

Comment: I think when you call a function, the function has it's own namespace scope. So these variables are in different scopes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of thing to understand here:

The variable `i` in `drawSquare()` and the variable `i` in `main()` are completely separate variables. They have the same name, but otherwise they have absolutely nothing in common with each other. You can have a thousand variables called `i` in your program and so long as they're all local to different functions they do not interact.

The second more subtle question would be what happens if you nest two `for` loops with the same control variable inside a single function.

```
for i in range(10):
    for i in range(20):
        print(i)
```

In this case there is just one `i` variable, but that doesn't matter. The inner loop reassigns the value of the variabel used for the outer loop, but you are allowed to reassign a loop variable in Python and it has no effect on the loop. Here you will get the numbers 0..19 printed out 10 times just as you might expect.

The `for` loop in Python iterates through a sequence (or anything iterable). It will set the loop variable to each element of the iterable in turn, but the loop control never makes use of the current value of that variable, instead it keeps all of the control information internally. That means you can't just assign the the loop variable and expect it to affect the iteration the way it might in some other languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest loops in one another if they're not in the same scope. Since you're calling the inner loop in another function, it has a different scope. The first 'i' is not known here, so you can't even access it and there's no conflict.

You can find more on variables and scopes [here](http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html#variable-scope-and-lifetime)

Comment: No, even in the same scope it would still work just fine. Python has no problem at all if you re-use a loop variable for other purpose in the same scope, it doesn't interfere with the operation of the loop.

Comment: You're right, I've had that one wrong. I've edited it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Both variables are in different scope so there won't be any clashes. One i variable in inside the local scope of the main function while the other one is inside the local scope of the drawSquare function.